# Short story, probably in Asimov's magazine in the early 2000s - rehabilitation through simulated reality; success is not killing anyone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, virtual-worlds, crime

In this story, a man gets irritated by someone he encounters, and kills them, easily (perhaps just by wishing them dead). It turns out that he is being rehabilitated for his violent tendencies - if he can make it through a year of simulated life without killing anyone, he gets released, but when he kills someone, he is sent back to January 1 to start all over again.  This guy has been stuck in early January for many iterations, but as the story progresses, he meets a woman (I think) who is in the same process, and together they learn to suppress their desire to kill.

Comment: Found a promising title in ISFDB - "I Wish You Dead" by Brian Plante - searching for more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["I Wish You Dead"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?89683) by Brian Plante (Analog, Feb 2000), reviewed [here](https://tpi-reads.blogspot.com/2010/):

> A man is in rehabilitation for causing a death after losing his temper while driving. He is in a computer simulation where he has to
> live “ordinary” life for a year. He can kill everyone else in a
> simulation just by making a wish. And almost everyone else tends to be
> very irritating. Only catch is that if he kills someone, he must
> relive that day again. And again. Fairly good and interesting story.
> Only: you are living in a world where you can do anything you want,
> and the only consequence is that you have to relive that day. And that
> is considered as a punishment?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely correct.